# Find the antiderivative...

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Find the complete solution of the given differential equation

$${dy \over dx} = {3x \sqrt{1+y^2} \over y}$$

I know how to solve it if the right side didn't contain either $x$ or $y$, but I can't think of a way to arrange them. I think I should solve for $y$, but I'm not sure. Could anyone show me the solution? Thank you

Comment: Hint: this is a so-called separable equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to separate the $y$ and $x$ sides. Multiply both sides by $y$ and divide both sides by $\sqrt{1+y^2}$ to get the $y$s on the left side and then multiply both sides by $dx$ to get the $x$s on the right side.

$$\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}dy=3x\cdot dx$$

Now integrate both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Arrange as follows :$$ {y\ dy\over \sqrt{1+y^2}}=3x\ dx={1\over2}{d(y^2)\over \sqrt{1+y^2}}={3\over 2}d(x^2)$$$$\implies\int {d(y^2)\over \sqrt{1+y^2}}=3\int d(x^2)$$$$\implies 2 \sqrt{1+y^2}=3x^2+C$$